# Stop loop and add element after 3 loopt

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I's trying to display a list of skills using ACF Repeater. I only want to show the first 3 skills and then add '...' after that. Every person has a different list of skills and they don't have the same amount either.

What I have so far:

```
<p class="vakgebieden">
    <?php if( have_rows('team_vakgebieden') ) {
        while( have_rows('team_vakgebieden') ) { the_row();
            $vakgebied = get_sub_field('team_vakgebied'); ?>
            <span>•</span> <?php echo $vakgebied;
                                
            if( $i > 3 ) { ?>
                <span>•</span> ...
                <?php break;
            }

            $i++;
        }
    } ?>
</p>
```

Now I see the following:

- Person with 9 skills: 5 skills showing + ...
- Person with 4 skills: 1 skill showing + ...
- Person with 3 skills: 1 skill showing + ...

I have tried multiple times but I can't figure it out...

Comment: You should set `$i = 1;` directly before the while-loop start. If the problem still exits, i need more code around this.

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, I'll add my solution

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I forgot to add `$i= 1;`, I also tweaked my code a bit: Only the three first skills are shown, if someone has more than 3 skills, '...' is added to the and of the list.

**Updated code:**

```
<p class="vakgebieden">
    <?php if( have_rows('team_vakgebieden') ) {
        $i = 1;

        while( have_rows('team_vakgebieden') ) { the_row();
            if( $i === 4 ) { ?>
                <span>•</span> ...
                <?php break;
            } else {
                $vakgebied = get_sub_field('team_vakgebied'); ?>
                <span>•</span> <?php echo $vakgebied;

                $i++;
            }
        }
    } ?>
</p>
```

Comment: you can also use the get_row_index() function provided by ACF to get the index of the current row. (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row_index/)